# How do I export my armature with the mesh?

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, export

When I export my model, I want to export its armature along with it so I can load the character into new scenes for animation. When I try to do this, Blender only exports the mesh, the armature is not connected to it. I tried applying the Armature modifier but that's a whole other mess, posing becomes impossible as soon as I apply it. What can I do? What is the method for this?

Comment: Did you parent the armature to the mesh before exporting? - Select the mesh (make sure nothing else is selected). Shift - select the armature. Press Ctrl-P (on Mac Command-P) > With automatic weights. Then try exporting again.

Comment: Thank you! This solved it.